# Python regex stop at ampersand

Tags: python, regex

I am updating a script that is parsing google search results. Google changed the way the results are returned and I need to update my regex. Currently the issue is getting the regex to stop after seeing the ampersand.

Current regex `re_urls = re.compile('<a href="/url\?q=(.*?)"')`

This returns for example:
`http://www.example.com/test&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=3gdhVOfSJOr1iQKnwoBg&amp;ved=0CBQQFjAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNHPaPBdpjIJFynGKhW1As1fg9r8Aw`

How do I get it to just return `http://www.example.com/test`

Comment: It is not recommended to use regexes for this. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1224076) out. Try [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) instead.

Comment: don't use regex to parse html

Comment: its google search results and I don't want to use BeautifulSoup I am trying to make the script as modular as possible.

Comment: @Phani: I find for fixed machine-generated HTML that regexes can often be a good solution.

Comment: @Siggy, there is a reason why people recommend not using regex to parse html and I don't get the modular part

Comment: @Siggy: parsing HTML is hardly modular. You have observed once already that any change in the format of the response wrecks your script. Instead, there is an API for that.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham modular as in aside from python nothing else has to be installed for script to work.

Comment: @Siggy, until your regex breaks again ;)

Comment: @Siggy: That's almost the exact opposite meaning as "modular".

Comment: Also, are you aware that it's generally against Google's Terms of Service to scrape their web pages when they provide APIs to access the same information? (That may even be part of the reason they periodically change the output format, although as far as I know they've never confirmed that.) If you're sure that there are no legal issues for you, or that you just don't care, that's fine, but make sure you're doing it knowingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't interested in the ampersands, you can use simply

```
r'<a href="/url\?q=([^&"]*)'
```

That uses a character class that excludes `"` and `&` characters, and matches all other characters greedily.